# How to tell who wants to be in war

Tags: clash-of-clans

I send out a message to the entire clan to asking them to comment if they do not want to be included in next war. This often doesn't work very well as people don't reply. I heard that there is another way to tell, if the left column on the star war page is red, this means they don't want to be in war? How exactly does this work?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to be in a war, you can go to your profile and opt out of wars, then when someone starts a war search, whoever is opted out will be grayed out in the selection. The person starting the war can still manually add people who are opted out into the war, or exclude people who are opted in by tapping the red/green box next to their name.

Answer (score 0):

When ever some one do not want to be in war, he can just simply opt out by pressing a button in his profile. This will make the star (in the clan member list) go red. This means he don't want to be at war and cannot be added to the war list (as said by [Dragonage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/127901/dragonrage))